# Java: Way to build a project then restart a server

Tags: java

Okay so I'm not sure how to make the title super descriptive or how to title this

also I'm not sure if this is the right one of the stack exchange networks to ask this on

anyway to the question:

So we have a project going on currently where we have a few programmers working on a java based gameserver through dropbox (Yeah I know we should be using something like git and we will soon)

then we have been taking the compiled version when we are done and manually moving over to our remote server and then rebooting the (game) server manually

could someone tell me a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You should look into using a build tool like [Ant](http://ant.apache.org) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org).  This lets you script the repeatable steps.

I'd recommend not starting with Maven as Maven expects you do use a certain structure.  And if you aren't using version control, you probably aren't yet ready for the "Maven way."

A build tool can definitely compile your code, create the jar (or other artifact) and FTP it over.  It may be able to restart the game server depending on what server you are using and what authentication you need to provide.

Comment: I don't know about game servers, but there are Tomcat Ant tasks that will deploy or undeploy a war file even remotely.